# Resizing Boxes in css to fit the 480px screen at the responsive process

Tags: css

I am coding this design and i finished it but there is a problem at the final step of my responsive process while trying to scale the boxes in my design to fit the 480px screen and i don't know what to do ?

I tried to give it width and height under @media(min-width: 480px) but i found the width and height in the other media sizes changed !

May you look at this section @media(min-width: 480px) and tell me how to solve this problem and resize the grey box and the green to fit this screen ? Thanks!

here's the code:

```css
body {
 background-image: url("../images/bg.png");
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

}

#wrapper {
 width: 895px;
 height: 493px;
 position: relative;
 top:-70px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 
}

h1{
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 300px;
 left: 125px;


 

}

 
h2{
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 240px;
 left: 540px;
}

.box {
 width: 578px;
 height: 350px;
 margin: auto;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(280deg, #ffffff, #eeeded); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(280deg, #ffffff, #eeeded); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(280deg, #ffffff, #eeeded); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(280deg, #ffffff, #eeeded); /* Standard syntax */
 position: relative;
 top: 150px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.box2 {
 width: 578px;
 height: 81px;
 margin: auto;
 background: #82ba2a;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 200px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.arrow-down {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0;
 margin: auto; 
 border-left: 30px solid transparent;
 border-right: 30px solid transparent;
 border-top: 30px solid #82ba2a;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 200px;
 left: 200px;
 z-index: 2;

}


.box3{
 width: 578px;
 height: 6px;
 margin: auto;
 background: #292929;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 230px;
 z-index: 1;
}


.logo{
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 60px;
 left: 300px;
}

h4{
 margin: auto;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #394256;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 30px;

}

h5{
 margin: auto;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #394256;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 25px;
}


button.login {
 margin: auto;
 width: 124px;
 height: 31px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 585px;

    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#747474), to(#2a2a2a));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #2a2a2a);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #2a2a2a);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6747474, #2a2a2a);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #2a2a2a);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #747474, #2a2a2a);
    
    border: 1px solid #2a2a2a;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2a2a2a;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #2a2a2a;
}

button.login:hover {
    opacity:.85;
    cursor: pointer; 
}

button.login:active {
    border: 1px solid #2a2a2a;

    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #2a2a2a inset; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px #2a2a2a inset ;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #2a2a2a inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #2a2a2a inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #2a2a2a inset;
     
}
.line{
 width: 1px;
 height: 180px;
 margin: auto;
 background: #e4e4e4;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 35px;
 left: 550px;
}

.contact_form{
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 78px;
 right: 385px;
 border-color: #dbdbdb;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 

}

 
.contact_form input, .contact_form textarea { 
    padding-right:70px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border:1px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius:2px;
    
}

.contact_form input:focus, .contact_form textarea:focus {
    background: #ffffff; 
    border:1px solid #82ba2a; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa; 
}

.shadow {
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 220px;
 left: 70px;
 
}


/*end*/

/* responsive part */

@media(min-width: 480px) {



 .box { 
  right: 60px;
 }

 .box2 {
  right: 60px;
 }

 .box3 {
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 230px;
 }

 .arrow-down {
  left: 140px;
  bottom: 200px;
 }

 .contact_form {
  left: 80px;
 }

 .line {
  left: 500px;
 }

 button.login {
  left: 520px;
  top: 390px;
 }

 h4 {
  right: 50px;
 }

 h5 {
  right: 50px;
 }



}





@media(min-width: 768px) {



 .box { 
  right: 60px;
 }

 .box2 {
  right: 60px;
 }

 .box3 {
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 230px;
 }

 .arrow-down {
  left: 140px;
  bottom: 200px;
 }

 .contact_form {
  left: 80px;
 }

 .line {
  left: 500px;
 }

 button.login {
  left: 520px;
  top: 390px;
 }

 h4 {
  right: 50px;
 }

 h5 {
  right: 50px;
 }



}


@media(min-width: 992px) {

 .box { 
  right: 20px;
 }

 .box2 {
  right: 20px;
 }

 .box3 {
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 230px;
 }

 .arrow-down {
  left: 180px;
  bottom: 200px;
 }

 .contact_form {
  left: 150px;
 }

 .line {
  left: 530px;
 }

 button.login {
  left: 560px;
  top: 390px;
 }

 h4 {
  left: -20px;
 }

 h5 {
  left: -20px;
 }

 h2 {
  left: 580px;
 }

 h1 {
  left: 160px;
 }

 .shadow {
  left: 100px;
 }

 .logo {
  left: 339px;
 }


}

@media(min-width: 1200px) {

 .box { 
  right: -3px;
 }

 .box2 {
  right: -3px;
 }

 .box3 {
  right: -3px;
  bottom: 230px;
 }

 .arrow-down {
  left: 203px;
  bottom: 200px;
 }

 .contact_form {
  left: 190px;
 }

 .line {
  left: 553px;
 }

 button.login {
  left: 583px;
  top: 390px;
 }

 h4 {
  left: 3px;
 }

 h5 {
  left: 3px;
 }

 h2 {
  left: 603px;
 }

 h1 {
  left: 183px;
 }

 .shadow {
  left: 123px;
 }

 .logo {
  left: 362px;
 }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Do Business</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
 <div id=wrapper>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="arrow-down"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>

  <h1><img src="images/logo.png" width="199" height="52" /></h1>
  <h2><img src="images/key.png" width="92" height="92" /></h2>
  <h3 class="logo"><img src="images/logofooter.png" width="178" height="47" /></h3>
  <h4><center>2015 COPYRIGHTS, ALL RIGHETS RESERVED FOR DO-BUSINESS SOLUTIONS</center></h4>
  <h5>
   <p><center><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#">Terms of Use</a></center></p>

  </h5>

  <button class="login" type="submit">LOGIN</button>

  <div class="line"></div>
  <form class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">

   USERNAME &nbsp; <input type="text" name="user">
    <br>
     <br>
      <br>
          PASSWORD &nbsp; <input type="password" name="password">
      </form>

  <div class="shadow"><img src="images/shadow.png" width="657" height="49" /></div>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach would be styling for mobile first, so no media queries is needed only for tablet and larger devices.

But if you want to continue without reshaping the entire site, just use max-width instead of min-width. This way it won't affect the larger resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this media query for mobile only

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px)
{
  //put your styles here
}
```